# How to print contents of a directory and save it NOT in the directory?

Tags: powershell, file-transfer, dir

I have a folder which freezes the whole system when I open it (probably there is a corrupted file). Luckily, I'm just interested in the names of the files in the folder.

So, how do I create a dirlist.txt from a folder in Powershell and at the same time not save it in the folder itself? Because if I do that, I won't be able to reach the dirlist. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pipe the output to a particular folder. Using the *PowerShell* or old CMD prompt.

`dir "c:\program files"> c:\junque\mystuff.txt`

will list the contents of the `C:\Program Files` folder and, assuming the folder `C:\junque` exists and that you have access to it, list the files in the document `mystuff.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-ChildItem C:\folder\ | Out-File C:\dirlist.txt
```

The first path is the folder you want to get the items of. You can also add the `-Recurse` flag if there are subfolders you'd like to get the items of.

Comment: I'd add the parameter `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` or short `-EA 0` to the gci.